# Set the cron expression value dynamically

Tags: spring, cron, scheduler

I want to set the cron expression value dynamically using controller. This is my code snippet.

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:properties/cron.properties")
})
public class SchedulerServiceImpl implements SchedulerService{

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerServiceImpl.class);
    @Value( "${cron.expression}")
    private String cronValue;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
    public void getTweetsFromAPI(){
        log.info("Trying to make request for get Tweets through TweetController.");
        log.debug("----------------Executing cron.expression {}----------------",cronValue);


    }
}
```

how can I set the cron.expression value dynamically after the deployment. If I used a controller and replace the properties file existing value, Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Logically your question is wrong. Cron expression is for scheduling a method for a specified time i.e. the method will be executed at a specified time say 12 noon everyday.

Now if you are dynamically changing the cron expression value that means you are controlling the execution of this method and not the scheduler which is wrong.

You can do something like below:-

```
@Value( "${cron.expression1}")
private String cron1;


@Value( "${cron.expression2}")
private String cron2;



@Scheduled(cron=cron1)
public void method1(){
//call to method
this.method();
}


@Scheduled(cron=cron2)
public void method2(){
//call to method
this.method();
}


 private void method(){
 //Your scheduling logic goes here
 }
```

Here you are reusing the method() to be scheduled at two different times.

Comment: Yep It make sense so what happens if you need to execute the same method in dynamic timestapms . My requirement is like this. I gave you a simple example. There is a football tournament going to be start and I want to execute a same method when the each and every game starts. (1) We didn't know the game start time until they publish the start time. (2) There can be multiple games at same time and we don't know how many games will be fired at same time. (3) Within seven days there can be a 32 total games. So do I need 32 cron expressions????

Comment: Your requirement mentioned in comment doesn't suit for the schedular usecase.